# Loading a page and executing a specific javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Beginner question.  I have a web page that uses the javascript prototype library to replace text inside a  element.    If a link is clicked, then a similar page is shown that has sliderjs functionlity.  The second page is designed to look and feel almost exactly as the main page.

Also on all pages I have a menu on each page which is positioned in the same place with the same functions.

I have a usecase where someone can go to page 2 then need to load and execute a javascript function on page 1.     I am trying to do something like:
`<a href="index.html AND THEN RUN javascript:showItem1()">Item 1</a>`

-----menu----

```
<!-- The menu looks the same for all pages -->
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:showItem1()">Item 1</a></li>  <!-- page 1 -->
    <li><a href="javascript:showItem2()">Item 2</a></li>  <!-- page 1 -->
    <li><a href="javascript:showItem3()">Item 3</a></li>  <!-- page 1 -->
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="puppies.html">Puppies</a></li>  <!-- page 2 -->
            <li><a href="kittens.html">Kittens</a></li>  <!-- page 3 -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

There is a (rather sickeningly cute) live demo at:  http://107.22.173.10

Here is the scenario:

- click Items 1, 2 or 3
- then click "puppies"
- click Items 1, 2 or 3 again.   Page 1 should load AND also the correct javascript.

How do I make the item links work from pages 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example with setting link on the page 2 like

```
<a href="page1.html#runFunction1">Run function 1 on page 1</a>
```

and checking if that hash exists on the page 1, like

```
if (window.location.hash == '#runFunction1') {
    function1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web page puppies.html doesn't have the implementation for showItem1(), showItem2() & showItem3().

Include mystuff.js which is having implementation for showItems() in puppies.html.

This should fix the issue.